# Split the string from right side to get the required output after second occurrence of special character

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, code, substring

I have requirement to get the string by splitting right side
Ex  **1.abc-sgd-ajj-test**  output needs to be in string = **abc-sgd**

**test-string-split-exam-demo**    output needs to be in string = **test-string-split**

I have tried

String str = 'this-is-test-data';
List res = str.split('-', 2);
System.debug(res);

but not sure how i can check from right to left and after second underscore i need remaining string in to variable
can someone please suggest

Comment: Do you *need* String.split, or do you just need a solution?

Comment: I need to get the out put  like below examples. Test-string-split-exam-demo    o/p = test-string-split

Comment: test-string-split-exam-demo o/p = test-string-split

Comment: which will be in string only ..which i wil use for further ioperation ,but not able to extract it.I need to check from right hand side 2 hypens and whatever is coming before that i need to take that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is arguably much easier with a Regular Expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(.+?)(-\\w+){2}$');
String input = 'test-string-split-exam-demo';
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
m.find();
System.debug(m.group(1));
```

Where the first part `(.+?)` is what we want to match, and the last part `(-\\w+){2}$` is what we want to ignore. Finally, group(1) gives us the first capture group, the part we wanted.

Comment: awsome.its working.thanks sfdcfox. Also i requst you ,can you just provide some guidance from where  i can learn regex part or regular expression stuffs